# Trying to stretch header all the way across the screen using CSS in a WordPress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress site that can be seen here:  [www.muslimsocialife.com](http://www.muslimsocialife.com)

I have created a child theme off of the parent theme "Januas" (which can be found here: http://www.showthemes.com/multiple-event-wordpress-theme-januas), and inside the child theme, I am trying to adjust the header so that the navy blue color you see, stretches all the way across the screen so that there are no white borders visible on the left or right.  Unfortunately, I am not sure how to do this.  I have the following code inside my style.css file:

```
/*
Theme Name: januas
Description: Child Theme for januas - Muslimsocialife.com
Template: januas    
Version: 1.0
*/

<head>
<style>

h1 {
   background-color: #001540;
}
h2 {
    background-color: #001540;
}
h3 {
    background-color: #001540;
}
h4 {
    background-color: #001540;
}
h5 {
   background-color: #001540;
}
nav {
   background-color: #001540;
}
div.menu {
   background-color: #001540;
}
 container {
   background-color: #001540;
}
.menu ul {
   background-color: #001540;
} 
</style>
</head>
```

The height of the header is fine, it's the width that I need to increase so that it stretches across the entire screen.  Can anyone see what it is I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the below code in your style.css

```
.wrap {
width: 96%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

to

```
.wrap {
max-width: 100% !important;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

set header

```
`
width:100%;
height:"whatever u want";

`
```

if this doesnt work do this

```
width:100%;
position:absolute;
height:"whatever u want"
```